# Each form control display on its own line and strech the entire screen

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My form looks great with Twitter Bootstrap 3 but I don't want it to look like this:

[image: good but not good enough]

And more like this:

[image: perfecto]

I was able to make my  button group on another page do this with `btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg btn-block` class. But I didn't yet find anything that does the same with form controls in Bootstrap 3.

My form code:

```
<!-- login form box -->
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="index.php" role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="login_input_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="login_input_username" name="user_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter username" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="login_input_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password"  id="login_input_password" name="user_password" class="form-control input-lg" class="form_control" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        // here I display the alert box
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BaddieProgrammer**, I have set up a **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/q1qx7uwd/embedded/result/)** to view two options and how they will look.

Both do what you are wanting here to stretch the form across the screen.
The **green** container has full width all bar the lg size.

The **blue** container uses Bootstrap classes to give you more control and a better look when viewed on all screen sizes.
Hope the top option will give you a better idea for how Bootstrap can work here for you.

Here is the normal size **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1qx7uwd/)** so you can look through the code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 bg-primary block">
    <!-- login form box -->
    <form name="loginform" method="post" action="index.php" role="form">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="login_input_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="login_input_username" name="user_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="login_input_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password"  id="login_input_password" name="user_password" class="form-control input-lg" class="form_control" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <!-- here I display the alert box -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like all answers are correct. This one is more elaborate though. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrapping your form fields in a `col-lg-3`, making them only 3 columns wide. Remove that class from the `.form-group` div.

That will make them stretch to the size of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of using the classes "form-group col-lg-3",
use this class "form-group col-lg-12". It should then fill the entire grid width.